# How to find the minimal thinness of a chain-graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a chain DAG, that is a finite seed DAG $\mathbb{G}$ that is connected to copies of itself into an infinite chain graph:
$$\ldots \to_{n} \mathbb{G} \to_{n} \mathbb{G} \to_{n} \mathbb{G} \to_{n} \ldots \tag{1}\label{orig}$$

Each connection $\mathbb{G} \to_{n} \mathbb{G}$ is exactly same, and consists of $n \gt 1$ directed edges.

I need to find a DAG $\mathbb{G}^\prime$ and $n^\prime$ chain connections such that the chain DAG
$$\ldots \to_{n^\prime} \mathbb{G}^\prime \to_{n^\prime} \mathbb{G}^\prime \to_{n^\prime} \mathbb{G}^\prime \to_{n^\prime} \ldots \tag{2}\label{sought}$$
is isomorphic to $\eqref{orig}$, has the lowest $n^\prime$ of all such DAGs, and $\mathbb{G^\prime}$ has the same number of vertices as $\mathbb{G}$.

A potential variation of the problem is that $\to_{n}$ can be directed in both ways as opposed to being directed only in one way.

Comment: Should the subscript on the first arrow in the second display be $n'$ rather than $n$?

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Comment: Can't we take a subset S of the $n$ edges of maximum cardinality such that $G\cup S$ is a DAG, and set $G'=G\cup S$?  It seems like we could have $n'=0$ if all $n$ edges point the same way.  Chain graphs are a new concept to me, so I may misunderstand.

Comment: @saulspatz I clarified the problem to hopefully eliminate your concern.

Comment: Thanks.  "The same number of vertices" is crucial.